# Streaming music across your local network with VLC: choosing which application I want to stream the music from?

Tags: windows-7, audio, vlc-media-player, streaming

I use [Airfoil](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/windows/) to send any audio to other computers: I can choose which application I want to stream the music from.

I know that VLC has a [streaming feature](http://www.overclock.net/t/378530/how-to-play-music-video-simultaneously-on-multiple-computers) to play music/video simultaneously on several computers: can VLC be configured to choose which application I want to stream the music from?

---

E.g. with Airfoil if I listen to music on iTunes, I select iTunes as the music source to be streamed from:

[image]

E.g. if I listen to music on Pandora through Google Chrome, I select Google Chrome as the music source to be streamed from:

[image]

I use Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VLC currently cannot be configured to choose which application the user wants to stream the music from.